# JavaScript that gets values from form and displays a message

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I want to write some JavaScript code that gets the values from this form and sums them together.  Then I want to display the sum in an alert message.  I don't have any JavaScript experience.

```
<form method="post" action="" >
        <div class="q1">
        <label>question</label>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="a1_1">
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="a1_1">
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="a1_1">
            <input type="radio" value="4" name="a1_1">
            <input type="radio" value="5" name="a1_1">
        </div>
        <div class="q2">
        <label>question</label>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="a1_2">
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="a1_2">
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="a1_2">
            <input type="radio" value="4" name="a1_2">
            <input type="radio" value="5" name="a1_2">
        </div>
        <div class="q3">
        <label>question</label>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="a1_3">
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="a1_3">
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="a1_3">
            <input type="radio" value="4" name="a1_3">
            <input type="radio" value="5" name="a1_3">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" >
    </form>
```

Comment: i want the js that get value from this form and sum and when click on submit show the score

Comment: Where is your JavaScript?  Stack Overflow doesn't exist to write the whole code for you.

Comment: i dont know js , because of this i post this topic , maybe someone can help me,

Comment: I think your first course of action is to actually read some tutorials/resources about JavaScript, and try to work out your own solution. You don't stand to gain any knowledge from someone else writing the complete solution for you, and it won't help you the next time you need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do but for calculating the sum of values of

> var q1_val = document.getElementsByClassName('q1').value;

similarly...

> var q2_val = document.getElementsByClassName('q2').value;

and

> var q3_val = document.getElementsByClassName('q3').value;

then

> final_value =q1_val+q2_val+q3_val

You can then do ...

> alert(final_value);